# Explorer crashes when clicking on any context menu command

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, crash, context-menu, windows-10-preview

I've recently updated to the new insider preview, but I don't know if this is related. Anyways, when I right click anywhere (on the desktop, inside of a folder) and click on any of the context menu options I have (namely, "Git Bash Here" or "Open with Atom") file explorer closes and the task bar resets. I take it these are signs of explorer.exe crashing.

Interestingly, if I click on some item and then pick any of the commands, it works. It only crashes when I click on empty space.

I've already tried using CCleaner to fix my registry, and manual inspection of the related registry keys also didn't produce any results.
What can I do about this?

Here are the event viewer logs:

```
Faulting application name: explorer.exe, version: 10.0.14366.0, time stamp: 0x575b788e
Faulting module name: windows.storage.dll, version: 10.0.14366.0, time stamp: 0x575b7903
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00000000003556ef
Faulting process id: 0x1c64
Faulting application start time: 0x01d1cba001341ccf
Faulting application path: C:\WINDOWS\explorer.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\windows.storage.dll
Report Id: 4b9f9854-7392-4a9e-8da0-742a32bb45b8
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

And the three information events after that error event:

```
Fault bucket , type 0
Event Name: APPCRASH
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: explorer.exe
P2: 10.0.14366.0
P3: 575b788e
P4: windows.storage.dll
P5: 10.0.14366.0
P6: 575b7903
P7: c0000005
P8: 00000000003556ef
P9: 
P10: 

Attached files:
\\?\C:\Users\Luka\AppData\Local\Temp\WER9A2C.tmp.appcompat.txt
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER9A3D.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportQueue\AppCrash_explorer.exe_85263293ddf02d16848fca77fdf0f5e14c161524_92466b16_cab_2b489a4a\memory.hdmp
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportQueue\AppCrash_explorer.exe_85263293ddf02d16848fca77fdf0f5e14c161524_92466b16_cab_2b489a4a\triagedump.dmp

These files may be available here:
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportQueue\AppCrash_explorer.exe_85263293ddf02d16848fca77fdf0f5e14c161524_92466b16_cab_2b489a4a

Analysis symbol: 
Rechecking for solution: 0
Report Id: 4b9f9854-7392-4a9e-8da0-742a32bb45b8
Report Status: 4
Hashed bucket: 
--------------------------------------------------------------
The shell stopped unexpectedly and explorer.exe was restarted.
--------------------------------------------------------------
Fault bucket 120493863433, type 4
Event Name: APPCRASH
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: explorer.exe
P2: 10.0.14366.0
P3: 575b788e
P4: windows.storage.dll
P5: 10.0.14366.0
P6: 575b7903
P7: c0000005
P8: 00000000003556ef
P9: 
P10: 

Attached files:
\\?\C:\Users\Luka\AppData\Local\Temp\WER9A2C.tmp.appcompat.txt
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER9A3D.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportQueue\AppCrash_explorer.exe_85263293ddf02d16848fca77fdf0f5e14c161524_92466b16_cab_2b489a4a\memory.hdmp
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportQueue\AppCrash_explorer.exe_85263293ddf02d16848fca77fdf0f5e14c161524_92466b16_cab_2b489a4a\triagedump.dmp

These files may be available here:
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\AppCrash_explorer.exe_85263293ddf02d16848fca77fdf0f5e14c161524_92466b16_2b68b3fc

Analysis symbol: 
Rechecking for solution: 0
Report Id: 4b9f9854-7392-4a9e-8da0-742a32bb45b8
Report Status: 0
Hashed bucket: d03c3e99aa0a078539db76e47d0c9165
```

Comment: Check "Windows Event Viewer" Check the "System Logs" and "Application Logs" see if there are any errors in there that are indicating what is causing the crash. to find windows event viewer just hit start and type event, should pop up. then paste any errors in the logs in your question.

Comment: I've added the logs to the question.

Comment: update to 14367 and look if Explorer also crashes

Comment: @magicandre1981 Any way to force that update?

Comment: switch to fast Ring and search for new updates

Comment: @magicandre1981 no dice. still not found. :-/

Comment: there are ISOs made by some users. get such one, mount iso, run setup.exe and select upgrade

Comment: build 14371 is now out: https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2016/06/22/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-14371-for-pc/ look to get such an ISO

Comment: @magicandre1981 Searching the web for some random ISO of a Windows build sounds like a tried and tested way to messing up everything. Where would I find reputable ones?

Comment: you can also get an ESD and convert it on your own to an ISO: https://cloud.mail.ru/public/7VtB/U1wFkd5Bo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've upgraded to a newer insider build (14371) and the problem is gone.

Comment: ok, so his was a bug in he older version.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a known issue when installing the technical preview / insider preview builds.

Microsoft have released a Patch for this.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3020114

Comment: Well, Windows Update did find another update but I'm on a metered connection at the moment so I can't try it out.

Comment: this update was for one the erliest Windows 10 Preview Buils from 2014 (Build 9879). He is using Build 14366.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, Explorer is crashing, and not displaying an error message.  If you haven't installed anything after you joined the Insider Preview and updated, then it's could be something that the update broke.  Open up your Event Viewer and see if there's something specific that's causing the crash.  Then use Nirsoft's [ShellExView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html) to disable it, or disable them all and see if that fixes your issue.

Comment: Check the edit for the logs.